# Background image leaving white line on right side of page with iPhone and iPad: newbie

Tags: css

I'm sure I've read the answer to my question in other posts:  but being a complete beginner to CSS I am stumped as to where I need to actually insert the code required to fix the problem.  Have tried all the various options listed in replies to similar queries, but I'm sure I must be putting the code in the wrong place as the problem still exists.

Problem:  background image does not display correctly in iPhone or iPad, leaving a white stripe on the right hand side.  Please can someone post a reply that shows my code as it is now and how it should look after, if possible using the media query solution (note I have pasted the existing code without examples of the various attempts to change it)?

www.shooterspattaya.com

Many thanks from a hugely frustrated newbie!

```
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
http-equiv="content-type">
<title>Shooters Pattaya Home Page</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
background-image: url(images/back.png);
background-position: center top;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
</style>
<meta
content="Shooters Pattaya Soi 7 Guesthouse Sports Coyote Bar Home Page"
name="description">
</head>
```

Comment: That's what happens when you use a background image that does not have the dimensions to fill the window

Comment: Thanks, so it's just an image resize issue?  It's currently 1329px 900px.  What should I resize it to?

Comment: Maybe your background image contains that white stripe?

Comment: You really shouldn't use a background image like that to the whole page, use a pattern instead that you can set background-repeat to, or use css background-size to fit/stretch the image but I suggest you separate the page background from the logo and other elements you now have in the same image

Comment: No, it just has a very narrow stripe about 4/5px wide with a shadow effect on it (if you view the site in IE or Chrome you will see what I mean).  It's not as wide as what is appearing on iPhone or iPad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this in your css:

```
html {
    min-width: 1420px;
}
```

Comment: How do you think it will look on mobile?

Comment: The same way it looks like desktop. If your are thinking about responsive site, sorry but with that table over there, it won't happen.